# Call a function that will start a NSThread on a pointer to function

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsthread

I'm trying to do something in ObjectiveC (which is far from being a language that I know) and I'm not sure it's possible.

I have an interface QAFeatTestCaseBase, with a function that will create a thread and start a function in it, and wait for it to finish :

```
- (void)callInBackground:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector
{  
   NSThread* thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(selector) object:nil];
   [thread setStackSize: 2*1024*1024];
   [thread start];

   while([thread isFinished] == NO) { usleep(1000); }
   [thread release];
}
```

And then I inherite from it to implement a function for a specific test :

```
@interface Bug8772 : QAFeatTestCaseBase
- (void) testBug8772
{
   [self callInBackground:self selector:@selector(Bug8772)];
}

- (void)Bug8772
{
    // do stuff..
}
```

But I have an error : caught NSInvalidArgumentException [NSThread initWithTarget:selector:object:]: target does not implement selector (*** - [Bug8722 selector])

Can you point me what I'm doing wrong? Or if there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selector` is already a selector. Don't wrap it with `@selector`.

```
- (void)callInBackground:(id)target selector:(SEL)selector
{  
    NSThread* thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:selector object:nil];
   [thread setStackSize: 2*1024*1024];
   [thread start];

   while([thread isFinished] == NO) { usleep(1000); }
   [thread release];
}
```

---

Note, `NSThread` is hard to get working correctly. I don't think the above code will do what you want.

For a better answer, look into [Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch?language=objc). Dispatch is also called GCD or Grand Central Dispatch.

Comment: Right, but even without @selector, I have same error.  I can't use GCD as I need to set the stackSize, and GCD doesn't allow it.

Comment: After fighting a bit, I get it working. The @selector has of course nothing to do here, and somehow I had called @selector(Bug8772:) instead of @selector(Bug8772) that would cause the issue of not finding the selector.